# How can i make a read only field on zend framework

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, model-view-controller, zend-form

I have this Field

```
$mobile = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('mobile');
    $mobile->setLabel('mobile')
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->setOptions(array('class' => 'full-width'))
    ->setAttrib('rows', 2)
    ->getDecorator(('label'))->setOption('tag', 'span');
    $this->addElement($phone);
```

but I need read only but I will add the content in data table

Answer (score 1):

You can set any attribute using `setAttrib` method.

```
->setAttrib('readonly', 'true');
```

Comment: Thanks  @s-rupali  but i can do update the data in My data base when i do update with this setAttrib('readonly','true') thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please update your question with database code as well?

Answer (score 0):

`setOptions` will set the attributes of the field. Just pass the `readonly` too. Try with -

```
->setOptions(array('class' => 'full-width', 'readonly' => true))
```

Comment: Thanks @sgt BOSE but i can do update the data in My data base when i do update with this setAttrib('readonly','true') thanks in advance

Comment: i want to update the data base with this field attribut readonly

Comment: It  should do that. What is the problem?